# alertbox to show the data when each td is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am showing the data  inside my own custom alert box when i clicked the first td(i.e row 1, cell 1) it showing alert box,then when i am clicking (row 1, cell 2,row 2, cell 1,row 2, cell 2)it not showing my alert box ,i think it taking the whole table as one div,but i want to display the alert box when each **td is clicked separately**,can anyone guide me how  to do this please see my code here  http://jsfiddle.net/Ur5Xn/5/

**my ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function showAlertBox(){
     $("#alert").css("display","inherit");
     $("#content").addClass("back");
    }
    function removeAlertBox(){
        $("#alert").css("display","none");
         $("#content").removeClass("back");        
    }

    $("#alertClose").click(function(){
       removeAlertBox(); 
    });
    $("#alertShow").click(function(){
       showAlertBox(); 
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: you can assign only one id to one element in document. Assigning same id to different elements would work for only one element if used as selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it as class because id for unique.

```
<td class="alertShow">row 1, cell 1</td>
<td class="alertShow">row 1, cell 2</td>
```

This will work now, here is the demo edited.
http://jsfiddle.net/Ur5Xn/7/

```
$(".alertShow").click(function(){
   showAlertBox(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign different Ids to each td, and same class. Then use the class as click selector.

```
$(".alertShowClass").click(function(){
       showAlertBox(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use classes, ids are uniques.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// ...
    $(".alertShow").click(function(){
       showAlertBox(this); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ur5Xn/17/

Answer (score 1):

Id is supposed to be unique, just the first one counts, so the length of $("#alertShow") will be always 1.

Try change the id="alertShow" to class="alertShow", and use $(".alertShow").click.

Or a better one, use $('table').on('click', 'td', function(){}), which is [delegated-events approach](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ur5Xn/11/)**

Use `Class` instead of `id` in `td` of `table`.

**for ex:**

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td class="alertShow">row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td class="alertShow">row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="alertShow">row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td class="alertShow">row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You gave same `Id` for all use `class` instead. An `id` must be unique you cannot use it more than once. But we can use a `class` for more than one elements.

Read this [documentation](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/)

```
$(".alertShow").click(function(){
       showAlertBox(); 
    });

<tr>
<td class="alertShow">row 1, cell 1</td>
<td class="alertShow">row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="alertShow">row 2, cell 1</td>
<td class="alertShow">row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesPJ/SfnZX/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code with `td` without the use of `class` and `id`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function showAlertBox(){
     $("#alert").css("display","inherit");
     $("#content").addClass("back");
    }
    function removeAlertBox(){
        $("#alert").css("display","none");
         $("#content").removeClass("back");        
    }

    $("#alertClose").click(function(){
       removeAlertBox(); 
    });
    $("table tr td").click(function(){
       showAlertBox(); 
    });
});
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/Ur5Xn/22/)**

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing for you to learn is a concept called Event Delegation. [Read this post, it's very enlightening](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

When you have read the post and some info on the topic, the answer is obvious: just attach an event listener to a parent node, and your little problem is solved. Here's your script:
http://jsfiddle.net/stanislav_kay/xGdZJ/9/

```
<div id="content">
  <table border="1" id="alertShow">
   <tr>
    <td id=11>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td id=12>row 1, cell 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id=21>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td id=22>row 2, cell 2</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```